# How do I add a top border image to my mainContent div in this existing code?

Tags: html, css

I tried creating 3 divs to add a top & bottom border image to my mainContent div, but I could not make it align. Is there a simple way to modify this code to add this blue border at the top & bottom of the main white section?

http://www.charissasantos.la/mezcaleria.html

Image of desired border effect here:
http://www.charissasantos.la/img/shot.png

Comment: Charissa did u get any idea from the answers........

Comment: I went for the simplest option to add it as a top background image. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to these answers, you could also apply the same `background` to both your `#footer` and `#mainContent` selectors.

For instance;

```
#footer {
  background-image: url(img/img-blue-border.png);
  background-color: #C39C5B;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: top;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#mainContent {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-image: url(img/img-blue-border.png);
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

[Working example here](http://jmeas.com/projects/so/guel/).

Comment: Thanks @jmeas, I'd love to do this. I tried it with this code but doesn't seem to work?   `border-top-image: url(img/img-blue-border.png);
-moz-border-image:url(img/img-blue-border.png); /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-image:url(img/img-blue-border.png); /* Safari */
-o-border-image:url(img/img-blue-border.png); /* Opera */`

Comment: Might it be that you haven't yet uploaded the files yet? I'm not seeing them in `/img`

Comment: Also, I just realized I didn't even mean to use `border`. All along I meant to be saying `background`! I think that neat solution up there that uses `border` had me confused. Anyway, I updated the CSS and added [a working page here](http://jmeas.com/projects/so/guel/).

Answer (score 1):

.............***[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/K1sx8yCA)***

Hi now used to this css for border of your `mainContent`

```
   #mainContent.grid_14 {
border-top:solid 10px;
border-bottom:solid 10px;
border-width:10px;
border-image:url("http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border3.png") 25% repeat ;
-webkit-border-image:url("http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border3.png") 25% repeat ;
-moz-border-image:url("http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border3.png") 25% repeat ;
    }
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/K1sx8yCA)***

**more info about image border** ***[link](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)***

Answer (score 0):

Actually for your desired result you will have to use `pseudo class` `:before & :after` like mentioned below the demo :- http://tinkerbin.com/7MrKH9Zz

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainContent">
asfdasdfafafafaf
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mainContent {
    background:white;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#mainContent:before {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/lPj6H.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:500px;
    height:7px;
    top:-8px;

}
```

Comment: This is a clever answer @Shailender, but :before only has IE8+ support. Some of these other answers will work just the same, but support IE6+.

Comment: ya i know Jmeas but now people are going fast foward i think how many persons are using IE6+ 7

Comment: It's true, but the data shows that there's still a big chunk of people out there who are still using those old IEs, unfortunately. Why limit your compatibility when there are just as good, yet more compatible solutions out there? =)

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="border"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="border"></div>
</div>

// CSS

.wrapper div {
clear:both;
}

.border {
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height: //height of image;
 background-image:url(image.png);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: While this would work, it isn't semantic code. There shouldn't just be `div`s that are there simply to display an image! If possible (and I think it is, in this situation), it's best practice to avoid this.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but considering non-css3 browser which doesn't understand border-image property, this is going to be work.

Comment: @Rohit, you want me to make a JSFiddle of this person's code?